# Preferred method of packaging Windows Mobile apps?

Tags: visual-studio, windows-mobile, packaging, activesync

Is there a preferred method of packaging Windows Mobile apps? Visual Studio creates an .exe file from the source, but the MSDN website mentions a CAB wizard. Can either work if it is just a standalone .exe? What all can activesync use to install on a mobile device?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the Visual Studio Smartdevice CAB Wizard. It will install icons on start menus, custom DLLs you need, etc. It also will register the proper information for deinstallation of your application. However, I don't know if there are better application packagers out there. I've used the CAB Wizard without problems.

Comment: In VS2005 you get to this wizard by: New Project->Other project types->Smart Device CAB Project

Comment: My preferred method of packaging Windows Mobile apps is "not" until Microsoft makes a concerted effort to compete with the iPhone, maybe even Android et al. This is a joke but there is always truth in humour so take it for what it is.

Comment: jdk, I agree with you. Programming Mobile is a PAIN: WinAPI is inadequate, no proper graphics support, .NET is sloooooow, the UI is archaic... MS must catch iPhone/Android or Mobile will die.